# Exception: NoSuchElement no such element

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

I need to open mail ethat I get from services https://10minemail.com/ru/

I get exception NoSuchElement if start test from command line. If I started in Intellij - ok.

```
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Отправитель']")));
    WebElement mailPage = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='viewLink title-subject'][text()]")));
    mailPage.click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should easily work instead Отправитель may cause text comparison error.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]")));
```